# Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, enrollment, value = numeric(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 330

Tags: r

This is the code

````
```{r}
# Create variables to show percent rather than counts of variables based on enrollment
# farms, foster, homeless, migrant, suspension_rate_total
merged_data$foster <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$foster)
merged_data$migrant <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$migrant)
merged_data$ell <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$ell)
merged_data$homeless <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$homeless)
merged_data$enrollment <-
  as.numeric(merged_data$enrollment)
merged_data[, "farms_pct"] <- merged_data[, "farms"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
merged_data[, "foster_pct"] <- merged_data[, "foster"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
merged_data[, "migrant_pct"] <- merged_data[, "migrant"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
merged_data[, "ell_pct"] <- merged_data[, "ell"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
merged_data[, "homeless_pct"] <- merged_data[, "homeless"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
merged_data[, "ell_pct"] <- merged_data[, "ell"] / merged_data[, "enrollment"]
```
````

This is the full traceback of the error

````
```
3.
stop(sprintf(ngettext(N, "replacement has %d row, data has %d", "replacement has %d rows, data has %d"), N, nrows), domain = NA)
2.
`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, enrollment, value = numeric(0))
1.
`$<-`(`*tmp*`, enrollment, value = numeric(0))
```
````

Here is the data

````
```
structure(list(schid = c("1030642", "1030766", "1030774", "1030840", 
"1130103", "1230150"), farms = c(132, 116, 348, 406, 68, 130), 
    foster = c(2, 0, 1, 8, 1, 4), homeless = c(14, 0, 8, 4, 1, 
    4), migrant = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ell = c(18, 12, 114, 45, 
    7, 4), suspension_rate_total = c(NA, 20, 0, 0, 95, 5), suspension_violent = c(NA, 
    9, 0, 0, 20, 2), suspension_violent_no_injury = c(NA, 6, 
    0, 0, 47, 1), suspension_weapon = c(NA, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0), suspension_drug = c(NA, 
    0, 0, 0, 9, 1), suspension_defiance = c(NA, 1, 0, 0, 9, 1
    ), suspension_other = c(NA, 4, 0, 0, 2, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```
````

*Additionally, I'm unsure how to add the data here in a tidy way. Any help on this front would also be much appreciated but not expected.

Comment: Your example is not working. Enrollment is not in the dataset you provided.

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you Roman! I didn't realize that I added enrollment in later, after this code. Phew, it's working now. :)